# write rule on NSG in azure

Tags: azure, networking, azure-rm-template

Lets say I have an NSG rule that I want to allow a user write permission to create an inbond rule. Access to any other resource should be blocked for that user.

How can we write custom RBAC rule in ARM Template?

Comment: Do you must need a Template ? You can use these  powershell scripts to achieve that: `New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId <your external user Object Id>  -RoleDefinitionName Contributor -Scope "<your NSG resource ID>"`

Comment: Hi, I tried to this PowerShell script but I am getting error can you describes in details  @wayne yang

Comment: First, you need to create a new guest user in azure active directory.Then use its ObjectID. If you have a guest user and have not assigned a role to it,just use its ObjectID. Then using poewershell to login Azure and put the scripts above. NOTE : you cannot use an internal user.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution1 Powershell**

**Step1**  You need to create a new guest user in azure active directory. Go to Azure portal > Azure Active Directory >add a guest user > Go to your guest user Email and accept the invitation.

**Step2** Using Powershell to login Azure with your Admin account.Run these codes:`AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId <your external user Object Id> -RoleDefinitionName Contributor -Scope "<your NSG resource ID>`

You can go to Azure portal to find the value of Object ID and the Resource ID.

**Step3** Login Azure portal using the guest user, you will find only the NSG in your all resources.

**Solution 2 Azure Portal**

**Step1**  You need to create a new guest user in azure active directory. Go to Azure portal > Azure Active Directory >add a guest user > Go to your guest user Email and accept the invitation.

**Step2** Go to Your NSG> Access control> Add> Select a role and Select the guest user> Save

[image]

**Step3** Login Azure portal using the guest user, you will find only the NSG in your all resources.

Comment: Hi,@Devendra Pal Singh , If this answer is helpful to you , please mark it as an answer to help more people.